# VB.Net Code on how to retrieve and navigate to a web page

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hello I'm having a hard time in navigating to a website I'm testin, I need to select all links and check each of them but I don't know how can I click the links or navigate through all the pages.
[the website that I need to navigate and click on links](https://hpe.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/Jobsathpe/0/refreshFacet/318c8bb6f553100021d223d9780d30be?ac=34824)

I tried using Html agility pack and I can't get the elements in the page

```
        Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()

    Dim web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb()

    web.UseCookies = True

    doc = web.Load("https://hpe.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/Jobsathpe/0/refreshFacet/318c8bb6f553100021d223d9780d30be?ac=34824")


    RichTextBox1.Text = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's being asked here?

Comment: Sorry I need to click each of those job openings but I don't know how to code it

Comment: Great. What have you tried so far? See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Added it in my main question. that's what I got so far

Comment: "Clicking" doesn't make any sense in this context.  You can "click on links" in a web browser, but you don't seem to be using a web browser.  It's not clear what you mean.  What's your goal?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this pattern in UWP . It is a good UI
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/05/01/master-master-detail-pattern/#.WSrAkFuGID4.twitter#5QUhldJxwFXLjl3Y.97

```
Public Sub New()
InitializeComponent()

ViewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_PropertyChanged

ArticleWebView.NavigationStarting += Function(s, e) 
If e.Uri IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not Await e.LaunchBrowserForNonMatchingUriAsync(ViewModel.CurrentArticle.Link) Then
    ' In-app navigation, so hide the WebView control and display the progress 
    ' animation until the page load is completed.
    ArticleWebView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
    LoadingProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
End If
```

End Function

```
ArticleWebView.LoadCompleted += Function(s, e) 
ArticleWebView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
LoadingProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
```

End Function
End Sub